# Unable to POST JSON data from multiple select element with Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to be able to send an AJAX POST request to my API endpoint to create a new instance of my `Asset` model with multiple Category instances referenced in my `Asset` model, hence the many-to-many field type in my `Asset` model.

I'm able to successfully POST and create new `Asset` instances, however my `category` field won't accept any data at all.  The category field remains empty when a new `Asset` instance is created.  I think it has something to do with my `CategorySerializer`.   I'm still learning how to use Django REST Framework so I'd appreciate if I could get some help figuring out how to work with serializers in Django REST Framework.

I've already tried modifying the `AssetSerializer` create method to handle parsing the JSON and validating the data but that hasn't worked. I've also tried other solutions suggested in other posts I've found on StackOverflow but haven't found anything that works for my situation.

Here's my `serializers.py` file:

```py
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class AssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True)
    description = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True)
    manufacturer = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True)
    uid = serializers.UUIDField(read_only=True, allow_null=True)
    borrower = BorrowerSerializer(allow_null=True, read_only=True)
    condition = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=Asset.CONDITION_TYPE, default='g', allow_null=True)
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    return_date = serializers.DateField(allow_null=True)
    checked_out = serializers.BooleanField(allow_null=True)
    category = CategorySerializer(required=False, many=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        fields = ('uid',
                  'name', 
                  'manufacturer', 
                  'model',
                  'description',
                  'owner',
                  'condition',
                  'category',
                  'borrower',
                  'checked_out',
                  'return_date',
                  'is_dueback',
        )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.borrower = validated_data.get('borrower', instance.borrower)
        instance.return_date = validated_data.get('return_date', instance.return_date)
        instance.checked_out = validated_data.get('checked_out', instance.checked_out)

        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.manufacturer = validated_data.get('manufacturer', instance.manufacturer)
        instance.model = validated_data.get('model', instance.model)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.condition = validated_data.get('condition', instance.condition)
        instance.category = validated_data.get('category', instance.category)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Asset.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Here's my `Asset` model:

```py
class Asset(models.Model):
    """Model representing an Asset"""
    uid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(Borrower, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    checked_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    return_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)    

    CONDITION_TYPE = (
        ('e', 'Excellent'),
        ('g', 'Good'),
        ('f', 'Fair'),
        ('p', 'Poor'),
    )

    condition = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=CONDITION_TYPE,
        blank=True,
        help_text='Asset condition')

    class Meta:
            ordering = ['return_date']

    @property
    def is_dueback(self):
        if self.return_date and date.today() > self.return_date:
            return True
        return False

    def display_category(self):
        """Create a string for the Category. This is required to display category in Admin."""
        return ', '.join(category.name for category in self.category.all())

    display_category.short_description = 'Category'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.uid} - {self.name}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('asset-detail', args=[str(self.uid)])
```

Here's my `Category` model:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    """Model representing an Asset category"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'd appreciate any help you could provide.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: So your problem is the `ManyToManyField`  doesn't work ?

Comment: You know you don't need to define every single field inside a serializer class, right ? You just make the `class Meta`, at least thats how i made my API

Answer (score 0):

i'm almost new in DRF but i try to help. why you writing all the field in serializer when you using `ModelsSerializer`? not need to telling `ModelSerializer` what type of field should be because you are pointing to model in `class Meta` and DRF know about fields and type and etc . second about `allow_null=True` in serializer, when Model haven't `null=True` you can't except DRF can create a not null-able field for instance with `null=True` so if you wnt a field can be null just add `null=True` in `Model` class . for your problem about ManytoMantry field try to use [Primary key relation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) for ManyToMany fields in your serializers then pass id of `Category` instances in list:

```
class AssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    borrower = BorrowerSerializer(allow_null=True, read_only=True)
    category =  serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Category.objects.all())


    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        fields = ('uid',
                  'name', 
                  'manufacturer', 
                  'model',
                  'description',
                  'owner',
                  'condition',
                  'category',
                  'borrower',
                  'checked_out',
                  'return_date',
                  'is_dueback',
        )
     read_only_fields = ( 'uid' , ) # this fields will be read_only
```

depending on how you using this serializer in your view for `save` and `update` have difference way. if your view is `generics` class so will do `create` and `update` itself by `POST` and `PUT` method .and for other class view that isn't belong to `generics` DRF view you can using `serializer.save()` to create a new instance.wish help you.
pass data something like:

```
{
  "name" : "foo",
  "manufacture" : "foo",
  .
  .
  .
  "category" : [1,2,3,24,65]
}
```